# Use natural identification of V with its double dual to prove that $U^{\bot \bot}=U$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I meet this question when doing my homework:
Given$U\subset V$,prove that $U^{\bot\bot}=U$,Hint: you may use the natural identification of $V$ with its double dual $V^{**}$,i.e,let $v\in V$ acts on $f\in V^*$ by $v(f):=f(v)$

I know how to prove $U^{\bot\bot}=U$ with addition theorem of basis, but I don't know how to prove it with notion of double dual space.

Comment: What is the “addition theorem of basis”? It would be great if you could include your proof.

Comment: You are right, I can only think of this proof that is not so concrete: Since $U\subset V$, There $\exists W \bigoplus U=V$ i.e $V$ is the direct sum of$ W$ and $U$, then if $U$ has a basis $\{u_1,u_2\dots u_m\}$ and W has basis $\{w_1,w_2\dots w_n\}$ then $V=span\{u_1,u_2\dots u_m,w_1,w_2\dots w_n\}$ So $span\{,w_1,w_2\dots w_n\}=U^\bot$and $U^{\bot\bot}=span\{u_1,u_2\dots u_m\}=U$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, $V$ is finite dimensional and $U$ is a subspace.

**Hint:** Let $\alpha :V \to V^{**}$ denote the natural identification. The restriction of $\alpha$ to $U$ (i.e. $\alpha|_{U}$) defines an injective map whose image is a subset of $U^{\perp\perp}$. By considering the dimension of the spaces of interest, conclude that the image is in fact equal to all of $U^{\perp\perp}$.